# d3.js visualization of some British disease data

Tags: html, css, d3.js

I've taught myself d3 (still learning), and have a finished visualisation that I'm more than happy with.

But i think (know) that the code can be improved and made more efficient. For instance, use a csv file for the data (don't know where to begin with that).

I believe i'm pretty good with html and css, but i was a little daunted by d3 and the html/css are a little messy (see the `<p></p>` in both the html css files).

I've attached an image of what it looks like (please ignore the data under South England: I know it's duplicated; I have to replace them with the actual data).

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300");

rect {
  stroke: white;
}
text {
  font-family: "Lato";
  fill: white;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

svg {
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-top:17px;
  position: fixed;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.p1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.p2 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-left: 550px;
}

.p3 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p4 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 230px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p5 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 380px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p6 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-top: 390px;
}

.p7 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 283px;
  padding-top: 390px;
}

.p8 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 553px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p9 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 723px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p10 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 896px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p11 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 553px;
  padding-top: 380px;
}

.p12 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 900px;
  padding-top: 380px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title>TreeMap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="1200" height="720">
    <g></g>
    <section class="container1">
      <p class="p1"> North England </p><p class="p2"> South England </p>
      <p class="p3"> Bradford City </p><p class="p4"> Leeds </p>
      <p class="p5"> Liverpool </p><p class="p6"> Manchester </p>
      <p class="p7"> Sheffield </p><p class="p8"> Brighton </p>
      <p class="p9"> Bristol </p><p class="p10"> Luton </p>
      <p class="p11"> Milton Keynes </p><p class="p12"> Southampton </p>
      <object class="Box" class="cancer"></object>
    </section>
  </svg>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
var data = {
  "name": "England",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "North England",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Bradford City",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Cancer",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#A8A7A7",
            },
            {
              "name": "CKD",
              "value": 3.21,
              "color": "#2F9599",
            },
            {
              "name": "CHD",
              "value": 2.57,
              "color": "#E8175D",
            },
            {
              "name": "Diabetes",
              "value": 11.92,
              "color": "#474747",
            },
            {
              "name": "Stroke",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#CC527A",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
        "name": "Leeds",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 2.50,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.52,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 3.29,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 6.71,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.82,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Liverpool",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 2.50,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 5.90,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 3.71,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 6.70,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.88,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Manchester",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.78,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 2.95,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.61,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 7.05,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 2.13,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Sheffield",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 2.54,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 4.57,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 3.85,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 7.08,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 2.13,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "South England",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Brighton",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Bristol",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Luton",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Milton Keynes",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color":"#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Southampton",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var treemapLayout = d3.treemap()
  .size([1000, 600])
  .paddingTop(20)
  .paddingInner(8);

var rootNode = d3.hierarchy(data)

rootNode.sum(function(d) {
  return d.value;
});

treemapLayout(rootNode);

var nodes = d3.select('svg g')
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(rootNode.descendants())
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'})

  nodes
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
    .attr('height', function(d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
    .attr('opacity', function(d) { return 0.8 /* has to be like d.value / max or so */ })
    .attr('fill', function(d) { if (d.data.color) {
                                  return d.data.color
                                } else {
                                  return "white"
                                }})
  nodes
    .append('text')
    .attr('dx', 10)
    .attr('dy', 8)
  .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.value;
  });


  </script>
</body>
```

[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please tell us more about what the data represent, how you generated the `data` structure, and what this data visualization aims to accomplish. See [ask].

Comment: Its for a university project, its from our healthcare system the NHS. Basically, for some context, according to various articles, there is a divide between the north of England and south. Where the north of the country apparently has a lesser quality of life and ultimately, die younger (research done by the university of Manchester). With this data, i simply want to compare various illnesses and diseases between the 5 biggest cities in the north of England, and the 5 biggest cities in the south of England (biggest cities based on population size). Cheers!

Comment: The thing is, you've hard-coded a bunch of colours in `data` and position coordinates in the CSS, so this is sort of like asking us to review the PDF output rather than the process that generates the visualization. Kind of an awkward situation for reviewers.

Comment: Is there some reason you opted for TreeMap layouts rather than [stacked bar graphs](https://datavizcatalogue.com/methods/stacked_bar_graph.html), which would be easier to compare visually?

Comment: I apologise, but as i subtly hinted in the description, i'm learning by doing. So it is very messy and awkward, which i apologise for. If you could point me in the direction of how to create a colour range, where each instance of cancer, diabetes, etc has the same colour. Or even the positioning of the titles (text) can be done via d3 too. I'm eager to improve on what i already have

Comment: My lecturer requested 'advanced' visualisations. So categorically no bar charts, line charts, etc. He's basically asking us to try new layouts, rather than the go to ones.

Comment: But that's just [chartjunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartjunk). You're probably causing [Edward Tufte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Tufte) to have a stroke right now.

Comment: I know, other than my treemap looking nice, it is confusing to others. But if i want a decent grade, i have to use the more advanced ones.. But as i said, i'm looking to make the code more efficient to help me progress

Comment: If you want something that looks impressive while being useful, maybe try plotting the data [on a map](http://datamaps.github.io)? Otherwise, you're just turning 1-D data into a 2-D visualization for no purpose other than "the teacher said so". (TreeMap is appropriate for hierarchical data, which this isn't.)

Comment: Yeah, i understand, i do plan to use a data map for data more suited to data maps. With this data however, the cities aren't close to one another and the map (from what i can imagine) wouldn't look great at all. I may take a gamble and use stacked bar chart for this data, then use this layout for other data. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Any idea on how to make a colour scale that reflects what i want though? Or even append titles that won't affect the visuals position rather than using css?

Comment: [D3 colours](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#color-schemes-d3-scale-chromatic). How to position titles is beyond the scope of Code Review, though.

Comment: I don't think its necessarily a bug, but scrolling in the little snippets output window moves weirdly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already very well explained in the comments section, the [treemap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping) is not the best visual encoding to represent your data. However, suggesting how to better represent the data you have is arguably off topic even for Code Review. With that in mind, I'll address only a couple of topics in your code regarding best practices, specially that ugly `<p>` positioning.

As I said, the creation of HTML `<p>` elements and their positioning in the CSS is not only strange and cumbersome, but it also will hider you in several ways. The common (and idiomatic) way to create the city names is using the very D3 layout you have, in the SVG itself.

First of all, don't use magic numbers. Set explicitly the width and height...

```
var width = 1000,
  height = 600;
```

... and use them to append your SVG:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
```

Then, you can use those values in the layout:

```
var treemapLayout = d3.treemap()
  .size([width, height])
  .paddingTop(20)
  .paddingInner(8);
```

Now comes the important part, which is printing the city names. First, get rid of all that HTML and CSS regarding the `<p>` elements. Also, remove the `position: fixed` for the SVG.

Have in mind that your layout has all the `x` and `y` positions you need. So, to print the city names, which have the `depth === 2`, just do:

```
var cities = nodes.filter(function(d) {
    return d.depth === 2
  }).append("text")
  .attr("class", "city")
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.data.name;
  });
```

Finaly, it's a good idea **naming** your selections. For instance:

```
var rects = nodes.append('rect')
  //etc...
```

If you want to print the regions' names, just use the same logic.

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
var data = {
  "name": "England",
  "children": [{
      "name": "North England",
      "children": [{
          "name": "Bradford City",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Cancer",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#A8A7A7",
            },
            {
              "name": "CKD",
              "value": 3.21,
              "color": "#2F9599",
            },
            {
              "name": "CHD",
              "value": 2.57,
              "color": "#E8175D",
            },
            {
              "name": "Diabetes",
              "value": 11.92,
              "color": "#474747",
            },
            {
              "name": "Stroke",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#CC527A",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Leeds",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Cancer",
              "value": 2.50,
              "color": "#A8A7A7",
            },
            {
              "name": "CKD",
              "value": 3.52,
              "color": "#2F9599",
            },
            {
              "name": "CHD",
              "value": 3.29,
              "color": "#E8175D",
            },
            {
              "name": "Diabetes",
              "value": 6.71,
              "color": "#474747",
            },
            {
              "name": "Stroke",
              "value": 1.82,
              "color": "#CC527A",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Liverpool",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Cancer",
              "value": 2.50,
              "color": "#A8A7A7",
            },
            {
              "name": "CKD",
              "value": 5.90,
              "color": "#2F9599",
            },
            {
              "name": "CHD",
              "value": 3.71,
              "color": "#E8175D",
            },
            {
              "name": "Diabetes",
              "value": 6.70,
              "color": "#474747",
            },
            {
              "name": "Stroke",
              "value": 1.88,
              "color": "#CC527A",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Manchester",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Cancer",
              "value": 1.78,
              "color": "#A8A7A7",
            },
            {
              "name": "CKD",
              "value": 2.95,
              "color": "#2F9599",
            },
            {
              "name": "CHD",
              "value": 2.61,
              "color": "#E8175D",
            },
            {
              "name": "Diabetes",
              "value": 7.05,
              "color": "#474747",
            },
            {
              "name": "Stroke",
              "value": 2.13,
              "color": "#CC527A",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Sheffield",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Cancer",
              "value": 2.54,
              "color": "#A8A7A7",
            },
            {
              "name": "CKD",
              "value": 4.57,
              "color": "#2F9599",
            },
            {
              "name": "CHD",
              "value": 3.85,
              "color": "#E8175D",
            },
            {
              "name": "Diabetes",
              "value": 7.08,
              "color": "#474747",
            },
            {
              "name": "Stroke",
              "value": 2.13,
              "color": "#CC527A",
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "South England",
      "children": [{
          "name": "Brighton",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Cancer",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#A8A7A7",
            },
            {
              "name": "CKD",
              "value": 3.21,
              "color": "#2F9599",
            },
            {
              "name": "CHD",
              "value": 2.57,
              "color": "#E8175D",
            },
            {
              "name": "Diabetes",
              "value": 11.92,
              "color": "#474747",
            },
            {
              "name": "Stroke",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#CC527A",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Bristol",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Cancer",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#A8A7A7",
            },
            {
              "name": "CKD",
              "value": 3.21,
              "color": "#2F9599",
            },
            {
              "name": "CHD",
              "value": 2.57,
              "color": "#E8175D",
            },
            {
              "name": "Diabetes",
              "value": 11.92,
              "color": "#474747",
            },
            {
              "name": "Stroke",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#CC527A",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Luton",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Cancer",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#A8A7A7",
            },
            {
              "name": "CKD",
              "value": 3.21,
              "color": "#2F9599",
            },
            {
              "name": "CHD",
              "value": 2.57,
              "color": "#E8175D",
            },
            {
              "name": "Diabetes",
              "value": 11.92,
              "color": "#474747",
            },
            {
              "name": "Stroke",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#CC527A",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Milton Keynes",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Cancer",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#A8A7A7",
            },
            {
              "name": "CKD",
              "value": 3.21,
              "color": "#2F9599",
            },
            {
              "name": "CHD",
              "value": 2.57,
              "color": "#E8175D",
            },
            {
              "name": "Diabetes",
              "value": 11.92,
              "color": "#474747",
            },
            {
              "name": "Stroke",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#CC527A",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Southampton",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Cancer",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#A8A7A7",
            },
            {
              "name": "CKD",
              "value": 3.21,
              "color": "#2F9599",
            },
            {
              "name": "CHD",
              "value": 2.57,
              "color": "#E8175D",
            },
            {
              "name": "Diabetes",
              "value": 11.92,
              "color": "#474747",
            },
            {
              "name": "Stroke",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#CC527A",
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var width = 1000,
  height = 600;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var treemapLayout = d3.treemap()
  .size([width, height])
  .paddingTop(20)
  .paddingInner(8);

var rootNode = d3.hierarchy(data)

rootNode.sum(function(d) {
  return d.value;
});

treemapLayout(rootNode);

var nodes = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(rootNode.descendants())
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'
  });

var rects = nodes.append('rect')
  .attr('width', function(d) {
    return d.x1 - d.x0;
  })
  .attr('height', function(d) {
    return d.y1 - d.y0;
  })
  .attr('opacity', function(d) {
    return 0.8 /* has to be like d.value / max or so */
  })
  .attr('fill', function(d) {
    if (d.data.color) {
      return d.data.color
    } else {
      return "white"
    }
  })

var cities = nodes.filter(function(d) {
    return d.depth === 2
  }).append("text")
  .attr("class", "city")
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.data.name;
  })

var labels = nodes.append('text')
  .attr("class", "label")
  .attr('dx', 10)
  .attr('dy', 8)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.data.value;
  });
```

```css
rect {
  stroke: white;
}

.city {
  fill: darkslategray;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.label {
  font-family: "Lato";
  fill: white;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

svg {
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-top: 17px;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This is a learning experience for me, as i've never used javascript or any of it's packages before; i'm learning as i go. The hardest part (of D3) is that there are many ways to do things, like anything. I just need to find processes that i'm comfortable with and build on them. (On a side note, appending text is by far the most troublesome for myself). Finally, i'm well aware that a TreeMap isn't the best layout for this data, and that a bar chart of some description would be. But my lecturer specifically asked for more advanced layouts, whether they're appropriate or not.

Comment: Everyone works, and i understand everything. Only thing is that how do i target the regions of the data structure?

Comment: Just use the same logic I used here, choosing the adequate depth.

Comment: Perfect, i had no idea that you could do that. Thanks for all the help. One last thing, i don't entirely understand that 'var nodes = svg.selectAll(null) .data(rootNode.descendants())' part of the code. Why could i have not used what i had 'var nodes = d3.select('svg g')
  .selectAll('g')'? Is it bad practice?

Comment: @JabroniPepperoni I'm glad you asked this! No, it's not a bad practice at all, but it's unnecessary: I wrote a Q&A pair explaining what is `selectAll(null)`, have a good reading: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908